# url routing on checkbox is checked in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

can we change URL when radio button selected. I am using angularjs?

following is my code and I want to change url when input radiobox is selected

```
<div class="switch">
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="week" id="week" checked>
  <label for="week" class="switch-label switch-label-off">
    Automatically
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" value="month" id="month">
  <label for="month" class="switch-label switch-label-on">
    Manually
  </label>
  <span class="switch-selection">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: which URL???...and its radio been mentioned not checkbox

Comment: What have you tried so far? I see nothing there that looks like anything else than plain HTML.

Comment: Why the downvote? User is asking for URL is general - is it really necessary to know the URL for you all to provide an answer?

Comment: There is no indication that the OP has even tried to solve this before asking. I'm guessing that's what earned a downvote. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS, you can use the `$location` service to change path as:

`$location.path('/new-route');`

On your `input` tag, you can then use the `ng-change` or the `ng-click` directives to call a function that will change the route. So, it can be something like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-click="changeLocation('route-name')>
```

With your controller having the following code:

```
$scope.changeLocation = function (newRoute) {
    $location.path(newRoute);
};
```